# C#'s regex not working like I want it too

Tags: c#, regex

I have an input string like this:

> \pard\nowidctlpar\qj\b0\scaps This
>   Agreement\scaps0  is made and entered
>   into this date, \{#DATEAGREEMENT#\} ,
>   by and between [removed]
>   (\ldblquote [removed]\rdblquote ), and its
>   successors and/or assigns, with
>   address at  [removed], and
>   \{#TXTPLAINTIFF#\} , (\ldblquote
>   Plaintiff\rdblquote ), Individually,
>   of ___________________, and,
>   \{#TXTPLAINTIFFATTORNEY#\} ,
>   (\ldblquote Plaintiff\rquote s
>   Attorney\rdblquote ) of
>   \{#TXTATTORNEYFIRM#\} .\par

and I want to do some parsing with regex.

This is the code I'm using:

```
temp = Regex.Replace(temp, @"\\{#.*#\\}", "_____");
```

The only problem is it matches the widest set, i.e. it takes out the whole paragraph because the paragraph ends with "#\}", how can I get to match each group? I.E., this paragraph should match it 4 times instead of once.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Did you try making it a non-greedy match?

```
temp = Regex.Replace(temp, @"\\{#.*?#\\}", "_____");
```

Answer (score 1):

```
temp = Regex.Replace(temp, @"\\{#.*?#\\}", "_____");
```

Appending a '?' to the '*' will perform a un-greedy search.  Your initial regex was performing a greedy search, so it would look for the largest possible match.

Answer (score 1):

As I recall, adding a ? changes an operator from greedy to non-greedy, so try this:

```
temp = Regex.Replace(temp, @"\\{#.*?#\\}", "_____");
```

Answer (score 1):

You're looking for lazy evaluation:

```
temp = Regex.Replace(temp, @"\\{#.*?#\\}", "_____");
```

may do it